# Some questions look greyed on Meta

Tags: support, meta, questions

I don't know why some questions are greyed on Meta. Is it something I changed in the preferences or a browser (I am on Firefox Linux) problem? I am talking about well received questions, not highly downvoted questions and answers.

[image]

Comment: you should probably provide a screenshot of what you're seeing; it might be browser; OS, or you specific :)

Comment: I will add a screenshot @postmortes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely you have [ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173/295232) one of the tags on those questions. This can easily happen by accident ([here](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14084/442468) is a recent case on our sister site Super User).

If you didn't intend to do this, there's a widget in the right sidebar on all question lists (including the [Meta home page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/)) where you can undo this.

Comment: I will accept your answer I had a tag in my ingore tag list I didn't know. Thank you. The problem is solved.